# Trigger galaxy S4 Infrared sensor App Development?

Tags: java, android, mobile, samsung-mobile

Hello I'am an complete noob in Android development and since i have the galaxy S4 with the IR sensor i thaught of start developping an remote wich works with almost every tv without configourtion. I know it is probably not the easyest app for a beginner but i thought i am quiet an expert in java so it would not be a big thing to learn. however first i want a button and if i press it it should send an IR code to the galaxy s4 IR sensor. I did som research and i found out that infrared codes are HEX codes

Example: Power on code for a JVC TV

```
0000 006d 0001 0011 0140 009e 0014 003c 0014 003c 0014 0014 0014 0014 0014 0014 0014 0014 0014 0014 0014 0014 0014 003c 0014 003c 0014 003c 0014 0014 0014 003c 0014 0014 0014 0014 0014 0014 0014 0379
```

how can i send this code to the IR output ar there any API's ? 
could you give me some examples or helpful Links
if you ar interested in my project you can add me on skype: jonijoni111

thanks in afford.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Someone wrote a sample application for the Samsung Galaxy Note. I tried the code for the Samsung Galaxy S4 and it worked as well:
https://github.com/rngtng/IrDude/blob/master/src/com/rngtng/irdude/MainActivity.java

Comment: Dude you can't imagine how happy you made me now i can do exactly what i want .. Its working !